# Rails3 singular route to mask :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In the Rails Guides under **2.5 Singular Resources**, it states

> Sometimes, you have a resource that
>   clients always look up without
>   referencing an ID. For example, you
>   would like /profile to always show the
>   profile of the currently logged in
>   user. In this case, you can use a
>   singular resource to map /profile
>   (rather than /profile/:id) to the show
>   action.

So I tried the example:

```
match "profile" => "users#show"
```

However, when I attempt to go to the profile_path, it attempts to redirect to the following, where id = :id:

```
/profile.id
```

This represents two issues:

1. I dont want the id to be displayed at all, and thought this was a routing pattern to mask an id
2. Using this method causes the following error. It also causes this error when I attempt to request user_path.

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User without an ID
```

I guess this is because the params being passed through look like this:

```
{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show", "format"=>"76"}
```

Am I using singular resources correctly?

My UsersController:

```
  def show    
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
```

My routes:

```
  resources :users
  match "profile"  => "users#show"
```

Comment: What does your `UsersController#show` method look like? Are there any other routes in routes.rb that have to do with users/profiles?

Comment: Provided updates containing my routes and controller

Comment: Thanks for adding the info. I think you should get it to work with my answer below. If you have more questions let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or

```
get "/profile/:id" => "users#show", :as => :profile
# or for current_user
get "/profile" => "users#show", :as => :profile
```

or

```
resource :profile, :controller => :users, :only => :show
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you want to use `profile_url` or `profile_path` you have to use `:as` like this:

```
match "/profile" => "users#show", :as => :profile
```

You can find an explanation [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3).

Secondly, in your controller you rely on `params[:id]` to find the user you are looking for. In this scenario there is no `params[:id]`, so you have to rewrite your controller code:

```
def show
  if params[:id].nil? && current_user
    @user = current_user
  else
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks for an :id because probably you already have a resource profile in your routes file:

```
resoruce(s): profile
```

If it so, try to shift that line under your new line `match "profile" => "users#show`

It should acquire less priority and your new line should be read before the resource: profile is read.

Let me know if it is the problem and if you solve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not have a 'profile(s)' resource and the only route that matches 'profile' is the match that I am trying to do with it. I also have the match route below the 'users' resource.

Answer (score 0):

i did this in this way:

```
resources :users
  match "/my_profile" => "users#show", :as => :my_profile
```

and to make it workable i have to edit my controller code too:

```
def show

    current_user = User.where(:id=> "session[:current_user_id]")
    if params[:id].nil? && current_user
      @user = current_user
    else
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb`enter code here`
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
```

and at the end just give a link to my_profile:

```
<a href="/my_profile">My Profile</a>
```